# FOS Rest bundle: avoid circular reference on a get response

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a REST Api done with FOS Rest bundle. I have a User entity and a Comments entity. So I want to get the user comments:
/users/{idUser}/comments
But the problem is in the response of the comment the User is included, and the user includes his comments, and the comments includes the user, and the user includes the user... so I end up with a inmense JSON response.

My getCommentsAction for the controller uses a repository and the findBy method, is there any way to tell FOS Rest Bundle to not to include the circular reference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JMSSerializer](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) is your saviour. If you see the [Symfony FOSRestBundle config document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/1-setting_up_the_bundle.html#c-enable-a-serializer) You must have a serializer enabled in order to get your data parsed correctly.

When you use `JMSSerializerBundle`, you can configure serializer `groups` like form validation and let `serializer` know which attributes to be exposed to API and which not.

Hope that helps!

Comment: freaking awesome bundle!

Comment: @Jeet - are you a god or something? you saved me hanging myself